# How to know array contents are empty

Tags: arrays, reactjs, conditional-statements

Lets say I have array like this :

```
[
    {
        "id" : "1"
        "name": "David",
        "age": "20"
    },
    {
        "id" : "2"
        "name": "",
        "age": "18"
    },
    {
        "id" : "3"
        "name": "Micheal",
        "age": "25"
    },
    {
        "id" : "4"
        "name": "Wonder Women",
        "age": "20"
    },
    {
        "id" : "5"
        "name": "Clark",
        "age": ""
    }
]
```

Some of the contents are empty. How to write the condition if "age" is null and "name" is null.

Comment: And if it is, what do you want to do with that?

Comment: I don't know the goal, but you can use filter, map, forEach, even classic loop.

Comment: inside your looping method the condition would be ... if( is_null($ar['age']) || empty($ar['age'])){}

Answer (score 1):

As your request is not definitive, I'm assuming you want the person elements that satisfy your criteria in a new array, called personsWithoutNameAndAge.

You can achieve this very elegantly, using functional programming:

```
const personsWithoutNameAndAge = persons.filter(person => !person.name && !person.age)
```

The [**filter()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

The function we provide the filter function (the argument passed to it) only passes the test (returns true) if both person.name and person.age are [**falsy**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy). Empty string, undefined, and null are all falsy and so the function will successfully work with any of these values representing 'null'.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the array and then use it where you need:

```
const myFilteredArray = arr.filter(item => {
  return item.name !== null && item.age !== null
})
// use myFilteredArray in your code.
```